# Crawling Pages after Authentication using Scrapy leading to DupeFilter Issues

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I plan to scrape some data from the admin panel of my website.

The way it works is that the script would login at the *www.example.com/administration* page and then go ahead and scrape follow all the links under the xpath of *`//tbody`* in the *www.example.com/administration/customers* page.

My Code:

```
class MySpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'auth'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    login_page = 'http://www.example.com/administration'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/administration/customers']


    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow='//tbody'),
             callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def init_request(self):
       return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
      return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'employee[email]': 'xyz@example.com', 'employee[password]': 'xyz'},
                    formxpath='//form[@id="new_employee"]',
                    callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
      if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
        return

      else:
        self.initialized()


    def parse_item(self, response):
      sel = Selector(response)
      item = Item()
      item ["Name"] = sel.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
      yield item
```

However, When I try and run this it doesn't really work and shows "No More Duplicates will be shown(see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)"

Maybe my code for the rules isn't correct or is there is something else which I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `dont_filter=True` on your request to prevent it getting dumped:

```
return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'employee[email]': 'xyz@example.com', 'employee[password]': 'xyz'},
                    formxpath='//form[@id="new_employee"]',
                    dont_filter=True,
                    callback=self.after_login)
```

This happens because you are logging in by sending the `formdata` with the `username` and the `password` to the same page you have already visited. But this time it is dumped by the [DUPEFILTER](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class).

**Note:** you can disable this filter completely for all requests by adding this line in your settings.py:

```
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy.dupefilter.BaseDupeFilter'
```

This will set the filter class to `BaseDupeFilter` which does no filtering at all.

Excerpt from the [official documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects):

> **dont_filter (boolean)** – indicates that this request should not be
>   filtered by the scheduler. This is used when you want to perform an
>   identical request multiple times, to ignore the duplicates filter. Use
>   it with care, or you will get into crawling loops. Default to False.

Comment: The DupeFilter Issues is resolved, however it still doesn't scrape the data as intended. Do you see anything else wrong with the code?

Comment: Please describe in what way exactle does it "not work as inteded". 1. Paste the scrapy console output, 2. provide example of correct/expected result 3. provide example of wrong result that you are getting.